# ImageMagick and imagick_type_gen don't recognize added fonts

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

Ok, I'm running a CentOS server, PHP 5.4.440 and ImageMagick 6.5.4 and I'm trying to add additional fonts, as an example let's say Lobster. Here's what I've done so far:

Uploaded Lobster.ttf to /home/myusername/fonts/

From SSH, ran "perl imagick_type_gen > fonts.xml". This resulted in a large font file, but contained NO references to either Lobster.otf or Lobster.ttf

Instead, I generated my own type.xml and saved it to /home/myusername/.magick/. Here's the markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<typemap>
    <type format="otf" name="Lobster" fullname="Lobster" family="Lobster" glyphs="/home/myusername/fonts/Lobster.otf" />
</typemap>
```

Via SSH, I edited /user/lib64/ImageMagick-6.5.4/config/type.xml and inserted the node that references the custom type.xml:

```
<typemap>
    <include file="type-ghostscript.xml" />
    <include file="/home/myusername/.magick/type.xml" />
</typemap>
```

Rebooted the server.

At this point, I can list the fonts using this:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$fonts = $image->queryfonts();
foreach($fonts as $font) {
    echo $font . '<br />';
}
```

And Lobster shows up in the list. However, converting an SVG to PNG isn't using the Lobster font. I've seen other questions in here similar to mine and they seem to work. What do I need to do to get the system to recognize the added font?

Here's the code I'm using to render what should be an image using Lobster as the font:

```
//Setup SVG to be read by Imagick.
$SVG = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$SVG .= '<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">';
$SVG .= '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="158px" height="92px" viewBox="0 0 158 92" enable-background="new 0 0 158 92" xml:space="preserve">';
$SVG .= '<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32 58)" font-family="Lobster" font-style="normal" font-size="20px" font-weight="400">Lobster</text>';
$SVG .= '</svg>';

$image = new Imagick();

//Convert SVG to JPG
$image->readImageBlob($SVG);
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");

//Save the thumbnail.
$save_path = 'lobster-test.jpg';
$image->writeImage($save_path);

echo '<img src="'.$save_path.'">';
```

I'm at a complete loss here. Help!

Comment: Perhaps a permission, or a security issue? Coping your configuration + test case works as expected on Debian 7.8 & Imagick 6.7.7. With the exception that I placed the font under `/usr/local/share/fonts/opentype` directory

Comment: Grrr, so it *should* work, but for some reason I can't get it going. What permissions do you have set on the fonts?

Comment: Let's try ruling out some hypotheses. Verify the otf file is good with: `convert -font /home/myusername/fonts/Lobster.otf label:Hello out.jpg`. Next, test the config by `convert -font Lobster label:hello out.jpg`. If both work, I'm guessing it's security policy related to PHP/HTTPD.

Comment: You're brilliant :) Ok, both tests work, so Lobster is definitely available by direct reference and by name. I thought I was going crazy there for a few hours.

So any thoughts on why it isn't working inside an SVG?

Comment: Maybe your PHP under Apache is linked to a different ImageMagick version. Maybe try making a stand-alone PHP script to run the same tests but not under Apache - just run the PHP from the commandline....

Comment: I looked into things a little more after your suggestion and found this. Apparently, imagick and ImageMagick don't talk much:

http://www.multipole.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25630

Looks like I'll have to dump all the fonts I'm going to use into the shared/fonts/truetype folder and see if that works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: UPDATE: the link I posted above holds the answer - thanks very much to Mark and emcconville for leading me int he right direction. Basically, you have to install the fonts on the server and refresh the cache.

Answer (score 8):

A full solution is discussed here:
http://www.multipole.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=25630

But here's the short version:

1. Make a directory for your custom uploaded fonts in
   /usr/share/fonts/default - I created a directory called "custom".
2. Copy the fonts you want to install to /usr/share/fonts/default/custom
3. Run the command fc-cache -v /usr/share/fonts

After this, ImageMagick will use the fonts in the SVG. The one Caveat is that you MUST use the font-family declaration embeded in the font. For example, Lobster.otf actually lists "Lobster 1.4".

If you've got the font installed and use the proper font-family name, you'll get your fonts rendered!

Comment: Great! I would highly suggest moving the font to `/usr/local/share/fonts`, or even `/opt/fonts` directory, and re-implement this solution. You don't want `yum` package manager to overwrite this change on next system update.

Comment: Thanks adding this answer! Lost a few hours trying to get custom fonts working and this solved it.

Comment: I spent an entire day trying to find an alternative to your answer above, because I thought getting my host to do it would be a PITA.. I tried embedding `<style />` in the svg with a link to the font.. I tried base64 encoding the font into the styles. I tried using `convert` on the command line, along with  `MAGICK_FONT_PATH=`. I tried installing Inkscape. I tried *everything*. Finally I threw in the towel and decided to try your answer on my own AWS ubuntu box, and it worked *immediately*. Now to get my host to do it.. Side-rant, it should NOT have been this difficult in 2024

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the fonts on your server, that's the only way I managed to resolve this issue.

You can check [Eric Green's](https://superuser.com/a/1212582/502128) answer on this.