# ImageMagick Not Changing Font on CentOS

Tags: fonts, imagemagick

I know I have this font installed and it shows up when I list all of the onts ImageMagick can see, but no matter what I change the font to in this code, the font never changes in my actual rendered image:

```
convert new-again.png -size 1800x420 -font Din-Condensed-Bold 
-pointsize 84 -background 'transparent' -fill black -gravity center  
caption:'Faerie Dragons love hot apple pies and also cold apple pies!'   
-gravity south  -composite  background1.png
```

I have tried other font names like Corsiva, for example and it doesn't change.

Here is my version info:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.4-1 Q16 x86_64 2016-10-13 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

The font list is huge, so I am just going to paste a partial list from that list.  The Din-Condensed-Bold font is the one I am wanting to use:

```
Path: /etc/ImageMagick-6/type-ghostscript.xml
  Font: AvantGarde-Book
    family: AvantGarde
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/a010013l.pfb
  Font: AvantGarde-BookOblique
    family: AvantGarde
    style: Oblique
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/a010033l.pfb

Path: System Fonts
  Font: Century-Schoolbook-L-Bold
    family: Century Schoolbook L
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 700
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/c059016l.pfb
  Font: Century-Schoolbook-L-Bold-Italic
    family: Century Schoolbook L
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 700
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/c059036l.pfb
  Font: Century-Schoolbook-L-Italic
    family: Century Schoolbook L
    style: Italic
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 400
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/c059033l.pfb
  Font: Century-Schoolbook-L-Roman
    family: Century Schoolbook L
    style: Normal
    stretch: Normal
    weight: 500
    glyphs: /usr/share/fonts/default/Type1/c059013l.pfb
  Font: DIN-Condensed-Bold
    family: DIN Condensed
    style: Normal
    stretch: Condensed
    weight: 700
    glyphs: /root/.fonts/DIN Condensed Bold.ttf
```

Comment: First, try simplifying your command till you get it working, something like `convert -size 1800x420 -font "AppleChancery" caption:'Faerie Dragons' a.png`

Comment: Then please run `identify -version` and `identify -list font` and paste the relevant parts into your question please. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell.  I updated the question.  Ok, so in my font list, I first have a list of fonts, and then I have a separate list of "system fonts" (see above).  The fonts I want to use are in this list, however, when I choose one they don't work.  However, if I choose a font from the first list, it does work.

Comment: Maybe check the permissions on `/root/.fonts/*` and maybe run your command with debugging, i.e. `convert -debug all -size ... -font ... `

Comment: Thanks much Mark.  Was finally able to get it to work with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30085275/imagemagick-and-imagick-type-gen-dont-recognize-added-fonts . Much appreciate your responses.